# DocuSignAPI - How to verify identity of signer in embedded form

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working to embed DocuSign signatures within an online form builder.

How do you handle verification of the signer for an embedded signatures? I only saw email validation option for powerforms, but not for regular embedded envelopes. There were legal/security concerns if the signer was the same person as the form respondent.

Comment: Welcome! ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!***

Comment: Hi @LarryK thank you so much for that information! Wondering if email verification is an option, similar to SMS but the code is sent via email? (Since you typed "and more" we thought we might check!). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Authenticating the signer: most of DocuSign's authentication options are available for embedded signing ceremonies. Before the signing ceremony is displayed, the signer is authenticated.

- Shared secret. If your app knows a secret of the signer (eg last 4 digits of social security number) you can have DocuSign use it to authenticate.
- SMS/telephone code. DocuSign will send a code to the signer's phone or make a call to them. This verifies that the signer has access to the phone.
- ID Verification. You can have DocuSign check the signer's government issued ID.
- Knowledge Based Authentication (KBA) DocuSign will ask a series of questions from the signer's credit report. Eg which streets have you lived on. Only available for the USA. [Live demo](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=KBA%20Authentication)
- Qualified signature approval via video interview. This authentication includes a video interview to authenticate the signer's identity.
- And more

How much authentication your application needs depends on your use case and the legal/financial repercussions of having someone either forge or repudiate a signature.

See the [API Request Builder](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com) and the Signer Authentication examples for live demos of many of these options.

Comment: ID Verification-
How we can verify by ID Verification on different country? Using ID Verification how we can identify that person is upload the correct ID proof. We are using the rest API docusign to use verification. For verification is there have any document or video, please share with us. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For embedded signing, the integrator is responsible for authenticating the signer that they are bringing into the embedded signing session.  If your application manages user identities and has an authentication method, you should document the method used and the collateral evidence, entering this data into the electronic signing record (Certificate of Completion).  You do this by using the 4 "security/auth" elements of the Recipient View API:  securityDomain, authenticationMethod, authenticationInstant, and assertionId.

Example:
App is a web app with typical user login by username and password.

- `securityDomain` - your app's domain, e.g. "mythical.com"
- `authenticationMethod` - "Password"
- `AuthenticationInstant` - date/time they logged in to YOUR app (nothing to do with DocuSign), such as session start time.
- `AssertionId` - anything that helps locate their login record, such as a record ID, identifier for a login audit log archive, etc.

Example:
App is used by different office/branch locations, accessed by customers entering that location. Customer shows personal ID to clerk.

- `securityDomain` - office/branch identifier
- `authenticationMethod` - "PaperDocuments"
- `AuthenticationInstant` - date/time associated with the customer visit - such as data entry by clerk.
- `AssertionId` - anything that substantiates ID presentation and verification, e.g. {clerkId}.{customer driver license number}.

Using these elements establishes the linkage between your auth methods and the envelope at the time the embedded signer entered the transaction.  This greatly increases your legal defensibility.  Adding any form of Recipient Authentication from DocuSign makes it even stronger.

Note: even if you don't authenticate the signer, you can still document the information, e.g. use "None" for `authenticationMethod`, use the HTTP Referer for `assertionId`, etc.